# Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Hash' not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to use Hash in my global functions file.

I keep getting this error.

Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Hash' not found

where my file below is located at:

/app/Helpers/functions.php

```
<?php

    use App\Http\Controllers\Hash;

    // If old password matches password
    function checkOldPassword($oldPassword, $user) {
        if (Hash::check($oldPassword, $user->password)) {
            dd('a');
        }
        else {
            return back()->withErrors([
                'message' => 'Your old password is incorrect.'
            ]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 22):

import the hash class from `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;`

Answer (score 4):

`Hash` is a facade. It is working in your controller because has been imported correctly: `use Hash;` However, in other classes or files, you need to import it as mentioned or using it without making an inclusion but backslash:

```
<?php

// If old password matches password
function checkOldPassword($oldPassword, $user) {
    if (\Hash::check($oldPassword, $user->password)) {
        dd('a');
    }
    else {
        return back()->withErrors([
            'message' => 'Your old password is incorrect.'
        ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error helpfully points out, there is no class `App\Http\Controllers\Hash` unless you created one. Remove that line your code should behave normally.

Comment: the Hash works in my controller file. the controller file has this namespace.
"namespace App\Http\Controllers;"
and "use Hash;"

Comment: The `use` operator outside a class definition is relative to the global space. Your helper is not namespaced and can therefore access the global space without using a fully qualified name or a use operator.